# Override status-private woocommerce product's variation

Tags: php, woocommerce

Perhaps an odd question, but is there a way to override the `status-private` of a WooCommerce product's variation programmatically?

Background: when you uncheck the enabled option for a product's variation, it gets the class  `status-private`, which means it's only visible for logged in backend users and hidden for frontend.

I would like the enabled option to keep unchecked, but do not want the private status. Reason for this are some rare stock statuses and it needs to be visible in the frontend. I can't find an existing hook for it.

[image]

[image]

```
function save_variations( $post_id, $post ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['variable_post_id'] ) ) {
            for ( $i = 0; $i <= $max_loop; $i++ ) {
                $errors = $variation->set_props(
                    array(
                        'status' => isset( $_POST['variable_enabled'][ $i ] ) ? 'publish' : 'private',
));}}}
```

Comment: Sorry but by default the class `status-private` is only assigned based on the post status. When switching a variation on/off, it makes no difference for that certain class.

Answer (score 0):

The following filter should help: 'woocommerce_post_class'

If you wish to remove that class, simply do something along the lines of this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_post_class', 'bbloomer_remove_post_class', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_remove_post_class( $classes, $product ) {
    unset( $classes[ 'status-' . $product->get_status() ] );
    return $classes;
}
```